# ComputedProperty only updates on second put()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have a `ComputedProperty` inside a `StructuredProperty` that does not get updated when the object is first created.

When I create the object `address_components_ascii` does not get saved. The field is not visible in the Datastore Viewer at all. But if I `get()` and then immediately `put()` again (even without changing anything), the `ComputedProperty` works as expected. The `address_components` field works properly.

I have tried clearing the database, and deleting the whole database folder, without success.

I am using the local dev server on windows 7. I have not tested it on GAE.

---

Here's the code:

```
class Item(ndb.Model):
    location = ndb.StructuredProperty(Location)
```

The inner Location class:

```
class Location(ndb.Model):
    address_components = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)  # array of names of parent areas, from smallest to largest
    address_components_ascii = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: [normalize(part) for part in self.address_components], repeated=True)
```

The normalization function

```
def normalize(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s.decode("utf-8").lower()).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
```

---

An example of the `address_components` field:

```
[u'114B', u'Drottninggatan', u'Norrmalm', u'Stockholm', u'Stockholm', u'Stockholms l\xe4n', u'Sverige']
```

and the `address_components_ascii` field, after the second `put()`:

```
[u'114b', u'drottninggatan', u'norrmalm', u'stockholm', u'stockholm', u'stockholms lan', u'sverige']
```

Comment: This behaviour is clearly documented in the ndb docs for computed property *Caution: ComputedProperties are not calculated on query, but rather on put(). If you update a model's schema to include a ComputedProperty, you should remember to update existing entities by loading and writing them to the Datastore. See Updating Your Model's Schema for more information*

Comment: No, this is not about old ndb objects. This is on put() on new objects, with the ComputedProperty in the Model code at put() time.

Comment: Okay I accept that. You now are running into order of events problem.  As you have discovered things aren;t quite working correctly.  You will find that StructuredProperty can't deal with a number of corner cases when used with other Models/Properties.  For instance PolyModel and also certain nested structures.  In your case the `_prepare_for_put` is probably being called on each property in an order that you don't expect.  `_prepare_for_put` is called on each property prior to the put, in the case of ComputedProperties its the trigger to perform the computation.

Comment: So calling _prepare_for_put() manually  before put() should fix it, without needing a put-get-put sequence? This really seems like some corner case bug, because it does not look hard to implement correctly.

Comment: Worth a try, but it will also depend on what state the StructuredProperty is in too.  What I have also noticed is that the order that properties are declared is not honoured, as the properties are stored in a dictionary (which implies hashing order of keys).  You will probably find _prepare_for_put is called in that order and this could have an impact on resolving complex dependencies/relationships in properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem seemed to be the order that GAE calls `_prepare_for_put()` on the `StructuredProperty` relative to the call to `_pre_put_hook()` of the surrounding `Model`.

I was writing to `address_components` in the `Item._pre_put_hook()`. I assume GAE computed the `ComputedProperty` of the `StructuredProperty` before calling the `_pre_put_hook()` on `Item`. Reading from the ComputedProperty causes its value to be recalculated.

I added this to the end of the `_pre_put_hook()`:

```
# quick-fix: ComputedProperty not getting generated properly
# read from all ComputedProperties, to compute them again before put
_ = self.address_components_ascii
```

I'm saving the return value to a dummy variable to avoid IDE warnings.

Comment: Why not just `self.address_components_ascii` instead of `_ = self.address_components_ascii`? It will touch the property in both cases.

Comment: `I'm saving the return value to a dummy variable to avoid IDE warnings.` My IDE removes code that looks useless. It's a habit from writing in `go`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this code on dev server and its worked. Computed property is accessible before and after put.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class TestLocation(ndb.Model):
  address = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
  address_ascii = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: [
    part.lower() for part in self.address], repeated=True)

class TestItem(ndb.Model):
  location = ndb.StructuredProperty(TestLocation)

item = TestItem(id='test', location=TestLocation(
  address=['Drottninggatan', 'Norrmalm']))
assert item.location.address_ascii == ['drottninggatan', 'norrmalm']
item.put()
assert TestItem.get_by_id('test').location.address_ascii == [
  'drottninggatan', 'norrmalm']
```

Comment: Yes, if you access the ComputedProperty in any way it gets computed. Maybe if I just read from all ComputedProperties in the _pre_put_hook?

Comment: It works for me even without accessing it before put. Anyway just accessing it before each put looks like **much** better solution that doing a double put.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation in `ndb`. Simply doing a `put()` followed by a `get()` and another `put()` worked. It's slower, but only required when creating an object the first time.

I added this method:

```
def double_put(self):
        return self.put().get().put()
```

which is a drop-in replacement for `put()`.

When I `put()` a new object I call `MyObject.double_put()` instead of `MyObject.put()`.

Comment: I wonder if you can manually compute the computed property before the first put so that you can avoid the double put.